# Set a certain percentage of a dataframe equal to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to set randomly dataframe values equal to NaN to attain a certain percentage of NaN.
So from the following Dataframe:

```
     name                       IS_030_EBITDA  IS_09_PostTaxResult
0    EISMA MEDIA GROEP B.V.     NaN            1292.0
1    EISMA MEDIA GROEP B.V.     2280.0         1324.0
2    DUNLOP B.V.                43433.0        1243392.0
3    DUNLOP B.V.                2243480.0      1324.0
```

I would like my Dataframe to have exactly 25% of the values equal to NaN (the NaNs below are just an example, this has to be done randomly):

```
     name                       IS_030_EBITDA  IS_09_PostTaxResult
0    EISMA MEDIA GROEP B.V.     NaN            1292.0
1    EISMA MEDIA GROEP B.V.     2280.0         1324.0
2    DUNLOP B.V.                43433.0        NaN
3    DUNLOP B.V.                2243480.0      1324.0
```

So what is important to understand is that I do not want to set 25% of the rows or of the columns to NaN, I want to have in my final dataframe 25% of the values equal to NaN.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this?:

```
# modified the data to make it read_clipboard friendly
'''
    name    IS_030_EBITDA   IS_09_PostTaxResult
0    EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V. NaN 1292.0
1    EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V. 2280.0  1324.0
2    DUNLOP_B.V.    43433.0 1243392.0
3    DUNLOP_B.V.    2243480.0   1324.0
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()

print(df)

df_sample=df.sample(2) # refer to the 'Note' section below
df_sample[['IS_09_PostTaxResult', 'IS_030_EBITDA']]='NaN'
df.update(df_sample)

print(df)
```

.

df original:

```
                     name  IS_030_EBITDA  IS_09_PostTaxResult
0  EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V.            NaN               1292.0
1  EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V.         2280.0               1324.0
2             DUNLOP_B.V.        43433.0            1243392.0
3             DUNLOP_B.V.      2243480.0               1324.0
```

df modified:

```
                     name IS_030_EBITDA IS_09_PostTaxResult
0  EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V.           NaN                 NaN
1  EISMA_MEDIA_GROEP_B.V.          2280                1324
2             DUNLOP_B.V.         43433         1.24339e+06
3             DUNLOP_B.V.           NaN                 NaN
```

Note:

"df_sample=df.sample(2)" -> you can add a logic to choose 25% of the total sample records and replace the value 2. Example:

```
# 25% data in each column 
x=25.0
factor = int((len(df)*x)/100) # factor=1 in the example above

df_sample=df.sample(factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand correctly, you'd like to uniformly choose 25% of the cells. This means that you can't choose records first (it'll distort the distribution). The following solution works for 25% of the cells:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10), "b": range(10, 20)})
total_cells = df.shape[0] * df.shape[1]

df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = "index")
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, total_cells, int(total_cells * .25)), "value"] = np.NaN
df.pivot(index = "index", columns = "variable")
```

Result:

```
         value      
variable     a     b
index               
0          0.0  10.0
1          1.0  11.0
2          2.0   NaN
3          NaN   NaN
4          4.0  14.0
5          5.0  15.0
6          6.0  16.0
7          7.0   NaN
8          8.0   NaN
9          9.0  19.0
```